# Ternary (and more!) overload of __add__ in Python

Tags: python, lazy-evaluation, ternary-operator

**Context:**

As a personal learning project I've been working on a simple computer algebra system. I have a univariate polynomial class where the coefficents to the terms are stored as a dictionary. Operator overloading the sum of two polynomials A and B involves finding the like terms, adding them and making a new term for the terms in A or B but not both (XOR). This works as expected but...

**Question:**

I noticed when I wanted to add more then two polynomials the process is slow as there is a common computation that could be done simultaneously. For example, given four polynomials (A,B,C,D) the sum:

```
A + B + C + D
```

is evaluated as:

```
((A+B) + C) + D
```

in other words:

```
add(add(add(A,B),C),D)
```

Could I write a special overload of the add function that would be called when there are multiple summations?

```
add(A,B,C,D)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's (sort of) doable with some hacking...

Basically the process is to not return a value after the initial computation - but rather, to return a promise that you'll compute the value at some point.

So `a + b` will return an object representing the calculation to be done (but not actually performing the calculation), which I'll call `(+ a b)`.

Then when it comes to evaluate the next addition, we end up with `(+ a b) + c` which evaluates to `(+ a b c)`, and so on.

Only when a property of the result is accessed do you actually carry out the computation.

Comment: Is this called something? I'd like to look at some examples of wheels before I reinvent my own. My guess is some kind of lazy evaluation, but that is to general a concept to be useful in a search.

Comment: @Hooked: It is basically just lazy evaluation. I'm sorry but I don't have any good examples on hand - I would think your best bet would be to look at how a lazy language like Haskell is implemented under-the-hood.

Answer (score 3):

> Could I write a special overload of
>   the add function that would be called
>   when there are multiple summations?

In short: No

Here's the list of all the operators and the parameters: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types

Using a custom function is your only option

Comment: And if you have a nice `Polynomial` class, you could implement it as the staticmethod `Polynomial.add` which would be just as neat.

Answer (score 2):

Have you actually profiled the code to figure out where your bottleneck is? Function calls in python are fairly fast.

Comment: I would suspect that the bottleneck is in "unpacking" the polynomials to their component terms, packing them back up, only to then unpack them again for the next add.

Comment: Anon is correct, however I deliberately avoided posting code to make the question more general. I'd like to know if the process is _possible_, not how to implement a specific instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **reduce** built-in function

like this reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) 
and it will calculates ((((1+2)+3)+4)+5).

more information about it you can get from here : http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reduce

Comment: Reduce, in this case at least, is identical to the statement 1+2+3+4+5. What I'm looking for is different function to be called when there are chained summations, one that is NOT binary.